# Checking a list for one of multiple values using "in" statement

Tags: python, list

I'm searching a list to see if it contains one of several elements within it using Python's "in" statement.  I'm finding issues however.  Here's a MWE:

```
print (1 or 2 or 3) in [1, 2, 3]

print (1 or 2 or 3) in [2, 3]
```

Both statements *should* return `True`, but the actual output is:

```
True
False
```

It seems that what the code is *actually* doing is simply searching for the number 1 in the list, rather than 1, 2, or 3.  Why is it doing this, and how can I modify the code to behave correctly?

Comment: `(1 or 2 or 3)` is just `1`, yes. You can see this with `print (1 or 2 or 3)`. Canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/3001761

Comment: `(1 or 2 or 3)` is an expression by itself, which evaluates to `1`, *not* an extension of the `in` operator. In `a in b`, you evaluate `a`, then evaluate `b`, *then* call `b.__contains__(a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(1 or 2 or 3) in [1, 2, 3]` is equivalent to

```
[1, 2, 3].__contains__(1 or 2 or 3)
```

not

```
[1,2,3].__contains__(1) or [1,2,3].__contains__(2) or [1,2,3].__contains__(3)
```

. The expression `1 or 2 or 3` is evaluated to `1` before `__contains__` actually gets called. `x or y` evaluates to `x` if `bool(x)` is true, otherwise it evaluates to `y`. (Since `or` is not a regular operator or function, `y` is *only* evaluated if `bool(x)` is false.)

To do what you want, you can use the `any` function:

```
print(any(x in [1,2,3] for x in (1, 2, 3)))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed in a nice, compact form.  It's strange that they implemented it this way, but I'm guessing there's a good reason for that.  Many thanks.

Comment: It's not that strange. It would be exceedingly difficult to define an arbitrary combination of `or`, `and`, and `in` keywords into some sort of embedded query language. `in` is very simple: it takes two arguments: the container, and the thing you want to check is contained.

Comment: Don't expect natural-language semantics from a programming language.

Comment: I thought that better use of natural-language semantics was one of the benefits of Python, although I suppose that's only relative to other languages.  Naturally there's a limit to how much that applies.

Comment: It's *more* natural, but that extends more to the use of words over symbols where possible (`or` instead of `||`, etc). Think about what the individual expression `(1 or 2 or 3)` would have to actually *evaluate* to in order to make `(a or b or c) in d` equivalent to `a in d or b in d or c in d`, while maintaining things like `if a or b or c: `. `or` is not a regular function, or you couldn't handle short-circuiting.